# auto_ptr pointing to a dynamic array

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

In my code, I am allocating an integer array using new. After that I am wrapping this pointer to an auto_ptr. I know that the auto_ptr call its destructor automatically. Since my auto_ptr is pointing to an array (allocated using new), Will the array get deleted along with auto_ptr or will it cause a memory leak. Here is my sample code.

```
std::auto_ptr<int> pointer;

void function()
{
  int *array = new int[2];
  array[0] = 10;
  array[1] = 20;

  pointer.reset((int*) array);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    function();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The array will *not* be deleted correctly. `auto_ptr` uses `delete contained_item;`. For an array it would need to use `delete [] contained_item;` instead. The result is undefined behavior.

As James McNellis said, you really want `std::vector` here -- no `new`, no `auto_ptr` and no worries.

Answer (score 8):

You can not use std::auto_ptr to handle dynamic arrays, because it can not know how to differentiate between delete  and delete[].

Moreover, `auto_ptr` is deprecated, in C++11 you can use `std::unique_ptr` with:

```
int *array = new int[2];
std::unique_ptr<int[]> pointer(array);
```

Comment: You would need to instantiate it with a special deleter, otherwise it will just call `delete`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee410601.aspx it is stated that a partial specialization unique_ptr<Type[]>manages array objects allocated with new[], and has the default deleter default_delete<Type[]>, specialized to call delete[] _Ptr

Comment: @juanchopanza  The template specialization will take care of it. No need of custom deleter.

Comment: Perfect, that is something I didn't know!

Comment: I prefer `std::unique_ptr<int[]> pointer(new int[2]);` as it avoids copying the pointer. Note, that with C++14 there will be `make_unique()` as we have `make_shared()` already today. This will provide strong exception safety when allocation unique pointers

Answer (score 1):

As others said auto_ptr is the wrong thing to use, std::vector is best. But you may also use boost::scoped_array. But note that you want to reset at time of creation otherwise you might as well use delete.
pointer.reset(new int[2]);

or better yet like this boost::scoped_array arr(new int[2]);

Also there is no point to to create a static std::auto_ptr pointer; in global scope.
This means it will get deleted only when the program exists, that happens anyway even if you leak memory.

Comment: scoped_array does not appear to do anything that unique_ptr doesn't.

Comment: yep its just there in older vc's if you use boost.